# How to sleep until condition is met

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I start my application I need to check if one of my service is running. If service is not running then I have to allow the user to start the service and then execution continues. If User chooses not to start the service then I have to Exit the Application. For every 10 sec I have to pop up the message to start the service,during this time program execution should not continue.Below is the code I have written. But I did not like the condition i<10 (what if user takes more time to start the service.Also I dont like to take this value from Config file) in the for loop.

Is there any way to achieve this without writing the condition? Can we achieve this using Timers also? Please give examples for same.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!CheckifServiceStarted()) {
        DialogResult dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Service is not Started.Please  start Service to continue", "Start Service", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.Yes) {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
        else {
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `break` in there? It will exit the `for` after the first `Sleep`.

Comment: Use a `while` loop instead? You can use `while(true)` until the condition is met.

Comment: Your comment "But I didnt like the condition i<10(what if user takes more time to start the service) in the for loop" implies you think the '10' refers to a timing element. This looks like it's a 'number of tries' figure instead (you can set this in any number of ways e.g. config file etc.). So why don't you like this number of tries or is the actual timing figure (10,000ms)?

Comment: @Enigmativity Removed Break...its my mistake...

Comment: Your `for loop` won't work as you expect I'm guessing as well, seeing as you're setting i = 0, then checking if it's less than 10 (yes), and then taking 1 off each iteration. Are you not expecting it to basically try and do 10 goes at it? So effectively, start i = 0, check if it's less than 10, if so increase it by 1 (i++)?

Comment: @BryanWoodford what if user chooses to cancel?

Comment: @sr28 updated code...

Comment: @reddy - then you exit with `System.Environment.Exit(0);`?

Comment: This seems a confusing user journey. You open your app, which checks if your service is running. If not you ask the user to start the service. If they click 'yes' you give them 10 seconds to do so. If they click 'no' you exit your app. Would it not be better to simply check the service is running on start up and on a button click? So your pop up would be something like "Service X not started. This is a requirement of MYAPP. Please start service.". Buttons would be 'Check Service' and 'Exit'. On clicking 'Check Service' you do the check again and if it's running it continues.

Comment: @BryanWoodford Thanks I was thinking same to do...

Comment: @reddy - I was just taking a line from your code above :)

Comment: @sr28 out of 100 times 99 times that service will be running in rare case user will forgot to start the service.so I dont want to make call everytime...I want to remind the user only if he forgets...,

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting. Check it as standard on the startup of the app. If it's not running then have your pop up prompt them, but give them a check again button, which then does the check again once they click it. Means there's no hidden timings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just break the sleep in small increment and check condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!CheckifServiceStarted()) {
        DialogResult dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Service is not Started.Please  start Service to continue", "Start Service", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dlgResult == DialogResult.Yes) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            if (!CheckifServiceStarted())
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    else {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

}